# PopUp in GridView

Tags: asp.net, gridview, popup

I need to open a pop up window when clicking a link in a grid view column. Can any one help me out?

i ahve a grid like this..

### Id  Name     o/p      status    details

1    xxx    78.9%      p       viewdetails 
                               -----------
2   yyy     65%        p       viewdetails
                               ------------

wat i need is , if i click the view details link from the grid, it should pop up the in put details of the corresponding output in a  grid inside a pop up.

Answer (score 1):

take a look at jquery and in particular the jqueryui.

the jqueryui has a great popup which does modal and everything.

http://jqueryui.com/demos/

and

http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/

Comment: the dialog is simply a div which jquery will hide for you on load and show when you press the link

Answer (score 1):

There are several jQuery plugins available to create dialogs very easily. One such plugin is jQuery Colorbox.

http://colorpowered.com/colorbox/

It is very easy to integrate and comes with several options to create dialogs.

For example :

```
$(document).ready(function () {    
      $(".cboxdemo").colorbox({ width: "80%", height: "80%", iframe: true });    
});
```

This code would show a popup on click of all hyperlink elements having class "cboxdemo". Content pointed by href attribute will be displayed in the dialog box.

Comment: You can check the html source at http://script.thetechhub.com. Above example is take from there.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need ASP.NET AJAX Control Toolkit. Try [ModalPopup](http://www.asp.net/ajaxLibrary/AjaxControlToolkitSampleSite/ModalPopup/ModalPopup.aspx)

UPD: something like this:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
    DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" ForeColor="#333333" GridLines="None">
    <RowStyle BackColor="#F7F6F3" ForeColor="#333333" />
    <Columns>

        <asp:ButtonField ButtonType="Link" Text="Show popup" />               
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
<asp:Panel ID="Panel1" runat="server" BackColor="White" BorderColor="#43AAE4"
    BorderStyle="Solid" BorderWidth="2px">            
        <div style="text-align: right; width: 100%">
        Some text in popup
    </div>   
</asp:Panel>
<cc1:ModalPopupExtender ID="modalPopupExtender" runat="server" PopupControlID="Panel1"
    TargetControlID="LinkButton2" DropShadow="true">
</cc1:ModalPopupExtender>  
<asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton2" runat="server" Text=""></asp:LinkButton>
```